# libcst: Inserting new node adds inline code and a semicolon

Tags: python, parsing, concrete-syntax-tree, libcst

I am trying to introduce a new node (as a new line of code), exactly before an Assign node.

The issue occurs when using `FlattenSentinel` to introduce the new node as I want the node to be separate, but libcst concatenates them using a semicolon (`;`), example:

```
a = 6
```

Becomes:

```
print('returning'); a = 6
```

Code to reproduce example:

```
import libcst as cst
class MyTransformer(cst.CSTTransformer):

    def leave_Assign(self, old_node, updated_node):
        log_stmt = cst.Expr(cst.parse_expression("print('returning')"))
        return cst.FlattenSentinel([log_stmt, updated_node])

source_tree = cst.parse_module("a = 6")
modified_tree = source_tree.visit(MyTransformer())
print(modified_tree.code)
```

I also tried introducing a new line but is looks even worse, code sample:

```
def leave_Assign(self, old_node, updated_node):
    log_stmt = cst.Expr(cst.parse_expression("print('returning')"))
    return cst.FlattenSentinel([log_stmt, cst.Expr(cst.Newline()), updated_node])
```

My desired result would be to insert the new node above the existing node (at same level  ), without the semicolon, like this:

```
print('returning')
a = 6
```

Is this possible in libcst?

Answer (score 1):

Your AST is like this:

```
Module
  FunctionDef
    SimpleStatementLine
      Assign
        Target
        Integer
```

When you try to replace the Assign with multiple nodes, you still need to respect the current line, which forces the semicolons.

```
Module
  FunctionDef
    SimpleStatementLine
      Call // Your print call
      Assign // a = 6
        Target
        Integer
```

Instead, you want to replace the parent `SimpleStatementLine` with a `FlattenSentinel` of new `SimpleStatementLine`s with your new nodes. So, you actually have to modify your code to operate on `leave_SimpleStatementLine`.

Answer (score 1):

[Ampersandy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17895638/ampersandy) provides explanation. You can search for `SimpleStatementLine` nodes with a `Assign` child and insert your nodes before founded node with `FlattenSentinel`. Here the code:

```py
import libcst as cst


class MyTransformer(cst.CSTTransformer):
    def leave_SimpleStatementLine(self, old_node, updated_node):
        if any(isinstance(child, cst.Assign) for child in updated_node.children):
            log_stmt = cst.parse_module("print('returning')").body
            return cst.FlattenSentinel([*log_stmt, updated_node])
        return updated_node


source_code = """
def func():
    a = 6
a = 2
"""

source_tree = cst.parse_module(source_code)
modified_tree = source_tree.visit(MyTransformer())
print(modified_tree.code)
```

which produces:

```py
def func():
    print('returning')
    a = 6
print('returning')
a = 2
```